# register with loop not giving expected output - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook that gives me the status of list of processes in loop but the output is not coming a desired

I am using ansible 2.7.1

```
---
- hosts: test_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: checking status
    shell: /etc/init.d/{{ item }} status
    register: output
    loop:
       - gdac
       - scac

  - name : print status
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ output.results }}"
```

expecting output  like (which given me the stdout or stdout_lines from the registered variable.

```
"msg":"Poller is Running\nSpooler is Running"
"msg": scac.db1: 3 of 3 running ( 7067 7060 7040 )\nayld.db1: 1 of 1 running ( 7114 )\nscac.db2: 3 of 3 running ( 7227 7216 7203 )\nayld.db2: 0 of 1 running
```

but am getting error

```
fatal: [test01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
``
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second task, you declared `loop` as an option of the `debug` module.

It should be an option of the task, not of the module. Since there is no `loop` declaration for the task, `item` is undefined.

You just have to fix your indentation:

```
- name : print status
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: "{{ output.results }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked.  Got to know the importance of indentation